# How do i assign unique identifier for a record in employee table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know it's first std question but someone asked me, but i was unable give him apropriate answer.
There are two tables `Employee,Technology` having many to many relation saved in `employee_technology_rel`.Employee table having fields- `emp_id (auto_increment)`,`emp_name(varchar)`,`DOB (date)` where Technology having fields `tech_id(auto_increment)`,`tech_name(varchar)`
 these two tables allows duplication of names.which unique constraint should i define for allowing unique entry?

Comment: Do you want the name to unique or you want to identify a record uniquely ? for uniquely identifying a row you already have id fields being auto-increment

Comment: for unique record i have "emp_id" which is 'auto_increment', I don't want to allow existing employee to insert

Answer (score 0):

You can define the unique entry on table `employee_technology_rel`,

```
ALTER TABLE employee_technology_rel 
       ADD CONSTRAINT emptech_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, tech_id)
// or if you have set a primary key already, you can still define via UNIQUE
ALTER TABLE employee_technology_rel 
       ADD CONSTRAINT emptech_uq UNIQUE (emp_id, tech_id)
```

what it does is it only allows *unique technology for every employee*.

in order for you to have unique `emp_name` on table `Employee` as well as unique `tech_name` on table `Technology`, you can also alter the table by adding unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT emp_uq UNIQUE (emp_name)
ALTER TABLE Technology ADD CONSTRAINT tech_uq UNIQUE (tech_name)
```

Comment: But during add new employee,i'm not assigning any technolopgy to him, i'm insert only insert the employee details.              Should i define any special column for uniqueness of employee details??

Comment: No - that's what the emp_id column is.  The *absence* of a row in the employee_technology_rel will mean that the employee has no technology assigned.  Neither the employee table nor technology table depend on the employee_technology_rel table; rather, that table relys on the other two, but only if an employee is assigned a technology.

Answer (score 0):

You want a composite primary key defined on the two columns in employee_technology_rel: emp_id and tech_id.

Answer (score 0):

> Unique Index and Unique Constraint are the same. They achieve same
>   goal. SQL Performance is same for both.
>
> **Add Unique Constraint**
>   ALTER TABLE dbo. ADD CONSTRAINT
>    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (  ) ON
>   [PRIMARY]
>
> **Add Unique Index**
>   CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
>    ON dbo. (  ) ON
>   [PRIMARY]

Source [sqlauthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) from Google search: "[SQL server unique index](https://www.google.se/search?q=SQL%20server%20unique%20index)".